# How can I use C# code in asp.net to pass a parameter to a JavaScript function?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

```
<% string s=LinkButton_ID.Text; %>
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton_ID" runat="server" Text="LinkButton_Text" onclientclick="JscriptFunction(...)">
</asp:LinkButton>
```

I want to send the "s" as parameter to JscriptFunction. I try JscriptFunction(<% s %>); but doesnt work. Do you have any suggestions? thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
JscriptFunction('<%= s %>');
```

Don't forget to quote the text value in your JS function call.

#### EDIT:

I didn't notice that your call to `JscriptFunction` is inside your server tag. If you don't have access to jQuery, the easiest way to pass the client-side text of the button is probably this:

```
onclientclick="JscriptFunction(this.innerHTML)"
```

**[Here's an example working on jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/qBupj/)**

You can also pass the client-side ID of the control and manipulate the value using JavaScript. Make sure you have `ClientIDMode="Predictable"` or `ClientIDMode="Static"` set on the control if you do it this way.

Comment: jscriptfunction('<%= s %>')" I try this but still doesnt work. Jscript function perceive that (<%= s%>) like string.

Comment: @kamal - See my edit. I suggest you pass the client-side ID of the control, then use JS to follow the client ID and retrieve the text.

Comment: onclientclick="jscriptfunction($('LinkButton_ID').Text);" ClientIDMode="Predictable" (I tried also "Static"). I wrote this code but the result of js function was "undefined". so js function perceive $('LinkButton_ID').Text as "undefined". have you any idea? thank u

Comment: Use `$('LinkButton_ID').text()`, not `.Text` as you have it. This will only work if you are using jQuery, because the `$()` function comes from there.

Comment: script/jquery-1.4.1.min.js .i use jquery and i tried .text() as you said. it also doesnt work

Comment: @kamal - I don't know why that didn't work, but check my latest edit for a simpler version. [I've tested this one,](http://jsfiddle.net/qBupj/) and it should work fine. If this solves your problem, please accept my answer by clicking the green checkmark.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to declare your code section to be javascript, and then you need to output the asp.net/c# value as a string. The easiest way is something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var s = <% Response.write(LinkButton_ID.Text); %>;
    //do your other javascript stuff
</script>
```

or

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var s = <%= LinkButton_ID.Text %>;
    //do your other javascript stuff
</script>
```

If you needed to do more logic around this, you could also stick a literal control there and output to it in the code-behind:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var s = <asp:literal id="litMyValue" runat="server">;
    //do your other javascript stuff
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple way u can pass/ instead you can use it in the function itself

### like

```
<script>
function JscriptFunction()
{
   var s = <%= LinkButton_ID.Text %>;
  // do what you want here.
}
</script>

<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton_ID" runat="server" Text="LinkButton_Text" onclientclick="JscriptFunction();"></asp:LinkButton>
```